# AI generated content should NOT be allowed on Stack Apps

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta

On February 14th, 2024 a new [network-wide policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626) goes into effect.

The de-facto default is that AI-generated content should follow the citation rules that already exist. In the announcement of this policy it is stated:

> Sites that have — before February 14th — made the Community Management Team aware of their superseding site policy on the matter that disallows this content instead of requiring it to be cited will have a different template that instead reflects that policy.

Since Stack Apps is its own [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) site, this question is a poll (upvote = I agree, downvote = I disagree - hence the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag).

> **Do not allow AI generated content on Stack Apps**

Additional considerations can be discussed in comments / answers.

Comment: I didn't bring the banner up yet that goes with the policy: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881 because any banner will be opt-in, so no banner will be shown, whatever the outcome of this poll is.

Comment: At the time of status-review (2024-02-14) the score was **+12/ -0**, so our policy is: GenAI content is not allowed on Stack Apps. Thanks for voting!

Comment: No banner was enabled, and [the help center article](https://stackapps.com/help/ai-policy) reflects the consensus from this post.